# Nuget restore for some team members does not work - Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc and other core packages

Tags: build, nuget

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community along with some other in our team. A mvc web application that I created works fine on my machine but when others get it to build, all packages download successfully but some of the core MVC such as Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Razor, etc don't install.

What was weird that on their machine, if they went into PM and downgraded the MVC package to 5.2.2 and then upgraded back to 5.2.3 it worked. But now when setting up the build on our build server, we get the same issue!

Any ideas why this bizarre behavior?

Comment: Different nuget versions?

Comment: @ErkiM. Didn't check that but why would that matter? When the Dev downgrades the version on 1 package and then upgrades back everything is as it should be

Comment: We are using VSTS and I've seen different versions of nuget.exe (not packages) having compatibility issues. And it can definitely be the case with nuget v2 vs v3

Comment: Good point @ErkiM. I'll have to check the nuget versions across all the team's IDEs. I'm on v3. We're using Visual Studio Online's hosted build agents, I sure hope there is a way to specify the nuget server's version some how in the build definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't check that but why would that matter? When the Dev downgrades the version on 1 package and then upgrades back everything is as it should be

EDIT (4th Oct 2016) after investigating a bunch of things:
One of the developers at one point committed the "Packages" folder which sits at the root which had the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" and other folders but without the dlls. This made the "Restore packages" not really "Restore" these as the folder already existed but when the build was run the artifacts weren't actually there in the folder to be moved into bin.

I deleted the packages folder, added it to gitignore and committed the change which made everything 'green'!