# AutoMapper 6.2.2 restore fails on VSTS build server

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, automapper

The Restore step fails in my build definition with this error:

> error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'AutoMapper (>= 6.2.2)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.

This is in a .NETCoreApp 2.0 that is using AutoMapper.  Restore succeeds locally in VS 2017.  Locally I am using dotnet sdk 2.0.0, and nuget 4.3.1.  On the VSTS (cloud) server, I am specifying the latest nuget version, 4.5.0.  I have tried many other versions, including 4.3.1 with no success.

I know there is an older, similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539603/automapper-package-5-1-1-is-not-found-when-nuget-restore-on-hosted-build-agent-i), but that was never answered satisfactorily, in my opinion.

If I look at the meta data in VS, at the top of one of the Automapper files I can see this:

> Assembly AutoMapper, Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005
>   // C:\Users\randyg.nuget\packages\automapper\6.2.2\lib\netstandard1.3\AutoMapper.dll

From this you can see it's taking the netstandard1.3 version, which is correct.  I'm wondering if the nuget on the build server is looking for a netcoreApp2.0 folder, rather than the netstandard1.3 folder?  Following this theory, I tried adding this to my .csproj file:

```
<AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);netstandard1.3</AssetTargetFallback>
```

My theory was this would tell nuget to look for a netstandard1.3 version of automapper if it couldn't find a netcoreapp2.0 version.  However, this didn't have any effect.  I later read that behind the scenes this fallback is already added automatically.

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.  I'm pulling out (what's left of) my hair on this, as this is the only package giving me trouble, and it's a critical one for my project.

On the build server I'm using .NET Core sdk 2.0.3 as well, if that matters.

Comment: Update - I just tried adding a new project to my solution, with a target of netstandard1.3, then adding AutoMapper as a dependency.  Restore is now working on the build server for this project.  So it seems the problem is specific to having a project with target = netcoreapp2.0

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with .net core 2.0 project. Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: starian chen-MSFT: you're right, I couldn't reproduce it either with a new project.  Then I deleted my dummy netstandard1.3 project, on my original solution and now it's still working.  I will clarify my steps as an Answer to this post.  Thanks for your offer of help!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this: since it seemed it might have to do with my target being netcoreapp2.0, I tried adding an additional 'dummy' project to my solution, with its target = netstandard1.3.  In this configuration, the restore/build succeeded.  I thought I would have to maintain this dummy project for this purpose, until I tried deleteing it and now the netcoreapp2.0 solution still restores fine without it.  I can only assume something was corrupted in the TFS build server NPM cache (even though I had tried checking the box to disable that cache), and once I got it to succeed once, it has cleared up whatever the issue was.